# CAML Query: use the value of a property of a lookup

Tags: caml-query

My project consists of two lists:

- a list of documents. This list has an SPUser field that determines who is responsible for that document.
- a list of projects. This list has a multiple lookup to the documents (among other things).

The goal is to create a view on the projects list that shows only those projects that contain documents for which the current user is responsible. I'm having a very hard time finding examples of such things online. Here's what I have so far.

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name="PROJ_Documents" />
            ???? //not sure what to put here
                <Where>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name="DOC_Responsible" />
                        <Value Type="Text">
                            <UserID/>
                        </Value>
                    </Eq>
                </Where>
        </Contains>   
    </where>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<Query>
    <Where>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="DOC_Responsible" />
            <Value Type="Integer">
                <UserID Type="Integer"/>
            </Value>
        </Eq>
    </Where>
</Query>`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want to use is a [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539975%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

http://spboom.com/sharepoint-development/sharepoint-caml-queries-samples/

http://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/

Check this links here you can find solution, base on your condition using tool or Query.